# Creating a list of nearest centre items

Tags: python, k-means

I am currently doing a project using k-means on a large dataset. I have wanted to stretch my brain a bit and do it without using any external libraries, solely by creating my own functions. I have gone fairly far but have encountered a problem of not being about to create a list based on where cluster centres lie.

For convenience sake, I have created a small subset data below to use, rather than using the whole dataset I have

```
dataset1 = [(6.08804, 3.457729), (4.147974, 5.275341), (6.538759, 3.670323), 
            (4.579573, 4.03559), (4.756026, 4.184762), (5.221742, 2.872705)]

cluster_1 = (0, 1)
cluster_2 = (1, 2)
clusters = [cluster_1, cluster_2] # although clusters not near data, it is to practise my model
```

Below i have 3 functions pertaining to the process of creating centre points for clusters

1. Calculating the distance between the data and cluster centres, where each point in the `dataset` is compared to each point in `cluster_list`

```
def calculate_distance(point1, point2):
    distance = 0
    for i in range(len(point1)):
        # Euclidian distance formula
        distance += (point1[i] - point2[i])**2
    # result then square rooted for distance
    return distance**0.5
    # end of function
```

2. Determining which cluster center a certain point is closest to

```
def find_nearest_centre(dataset1, clusters):
    nearest_point = []
    min_distance = 100000
    # obtaining sample from cluster list
    for c in clusters:
        # using distance formula above to calculate distance between points
        distance = calculate_distance(c, dataset)
        if distance < min_distance:
            min_distance = distance
        nearest_point.append(min_distance)
        
    return nearest_point
```

3. Creating two lists, one for each cluster, containing coordinates of data that are part of that cluster.

```
def create_list(dataset1, clusters):
    # new lists created for 2 clusters
    list_1 = []
    list_2 = []
    for d in dataset1:
        # using nearest_centre formula to determine which points are closest to centres
        nearest_centre = find_nearest_centre(d, clusters)
        # adding closest coordinates to list_1 for cluster 1 and list_2 for cluster 2
        if nearest_centre == clusters[0]:
            list_1.append(d)
        elif nearest_centre == clusters[1]:
            list_2.append(d)
        
    return list_1, list_2
```

Now to my problem. When I run the function  `create_list` it only creates two empty lists, not appending each coordinate, as is intended. Although not realistic, if the first 3 values were in first cluster, and final 3 were closest to second cluster, the output desired would be:

```
create_list(dataset1, clusters) # this is only function needed to operate ideally

list_1 = [(6.08804, 3.457729), (4.147974, 5.275341), (6.538759, 3.670323)] # list of tuples output
list_2 = [(4.579573, 4.03559), (4.756026, 4.184762), (5.221742, 2.872705)] # list of tuples output
```

I would appreciate any help I can get, obviously sticking to the theme of using no external packages. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting empty lists because you are comparing clusters to points so there are no possible matches.

Return the nearest cluster instead of the point from

```
def find_nearest_centre(dataset, clusters):
    min_distance = float("inf")
    # obtaining sample from cluster list
    for c in clusters:
        # using distance formula above to calculate distance between points
        distance = calculate_distance(c, dataset)
        if distance < min_distance:
            min_distance = distance
            nearest_cluster = c

    return nearest_cluster
```

and then compare clusters to clusters

```
def create_list(dataset1, clusters):
    # new lists created for 2 clusters
    list_1 = []
    list_2 = []
    for d in dataset1:
        # using nearest_centre formula to determine which points are closest to centres
        nearest_cluster = find_nearest_centre(d, clusters)
        # adding closest coordinates to list_1 for cluster 1 and list_2 for cluster 2
        if nearest_cluster == clusters[0]:
            list_1.append(d)
        elif nearest_cluster == clusters[1]:
            list_2.append(d)
        else:
            print("No match")

    return list_1, list_2
```

The output is not as you expected, but just from looking at it I think `cluster_1` is supposed to be always closer in this case.

```
list_1 = []
list_2 = [(6.08804, 3.457729), (4.147974, 5.275341), (6.538759, 3.670323), (4.579573, 4.03559), (4.756026, 4.184762), (5.221742, 2.872705)]
```